# When using view.window?.rootViewController to change the view based on an if statement, the embedded controllers are not activated

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

So I have an if statement that has 2 outcomes, `rootViewController` becomes `loginViewController` or `mainSearchViewController`. The storyboard for `mainSearchViewController` has an embedded `TabViewController` and a `NavigationViewController`. However, by setting the root view controller, I lose access to both the `TabViewController` and a `NavigationViewController`and its only the `mainSearchViewController` that is active. Here is my code:

```
 func setRootViewController() {
    if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
        let mainSearchViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.Storyboard.mainSearchViewController)

        view.window?.rootViewController = mainSearchViewController
        view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()


    } else {

        let loginSearchViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.Storyboard.loginViewController) 

        view.window?.rootViewController = loginSearchViewController
        view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

[image: Lose access to Tab Bar Controller and Nav Controller he making the root view controller the view on the very right]

Lose access to Tab Bar Controller and Nav Controller when making the root view controller the view on the very right

Edit: I have tried to set the `rootViewController` to the Tab Controller, this allows me to use the tab functionality but I still don't have access to the Nav Controller. Same goes for the Nav Controller, it works when it is the root view controller but there is no Tab Controller functionality

Edit 2: In the `viewDidLoad()` of the `mainSearchViewController`navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false` and I have the root view controller as the Tab Bar Controller. I can access the tab icons, and I can see the navigation bar, but the navigation functionality when tapping on a cell doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing rootViewController is likely causing your problem since tabViewController probably doesn't have loginViewController as a tab.

If you need to display loginViewController based on an if statement, it's better practice to show it using something like:

`navViewController.pushViewController(loginViewController, animated: true`)

Comment: Ohh ok. When I did that, I got access to the functionality of the navigation controller, but on the 'Main Search Controller', the back button is visible and when I press it, it goes back to the same view, without the back button. I just put 'navViewController.navigationBar.isHidden = true' and it works now. Thanks

Comment: Happy to help, @equ1nox!